# Can I travel from India to USA via a London Heathrow layover?

Tags: usa, uk, air-travel, transit, travel-ban

Can I travel from India to USA via layover Heathrow (LHR)?

Does this occur under travel ban or do I need to change the flight?

Comment: Do you mean you have a UK travel ban?

Comment: I think Tarun is asking about the Presidential Proclamation which bans entry to the US from anyone who has been in the UK (or numerous other states) within the previous 14 days. But the question is unclear.

Comment: It may also (though it is unlikely) relate to the restrictions of entry into the UK due to Covid-19 (which are quarantine requirements rather than an outright ban if I followed things correctly).

Comment: @Tarun Your question is likely to get closed unless you provide more info to enable someone to give a reliable answer. Eg are you asking about both UK and USA, or just one of them? How long is your layover? Will you need to clear Immigration in UK to claim and re-check your baggage? What is your USA immigration status?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I travel from India to USA via layover Heathrow (LHR)?

Probably not.

> Does this occur under travel ban or do I need to change the flight?

Because you would be stopping in a UK airport, you are considered to have been in the UK for the purposes of the ban.  If you fall under any of the exceptions in the ban, however, you should be able to make this trip.